# Why does the scope of a type matter when inferring generics from decorators in TypeScript v5+?

Tags: typescript, decorator, type-inference

Let's say you have a decorator factory function which returns a decorator to be put on class fields and which adds metadata for validating the field as an email:

```js
// email.ts

export type DecoratorFactory<This, Value> = (
  target: undefined, 
  context: ClassFieldDecoratorContext<This, Value>
) => void;

/** @template This  - Class constructor */
/** @template Value - Field type */
export function Email<This, Value extends string | undefined | null>(
  options?: API.Decorator.Options
): DecoratorFactory<This, Value>;
```

As you can see, the `DecoratorFactory` is defined inside `email.ts`. In this scenario the following code block successfully infers the generics of `This` and `Value` as `TestClass` and `string`

```js
import { Email } from "./email";

class TestClass {
  @Email() // <This, Value> evaluates to <TestClass, string>
  field: string; 
}
```

However, if you were to extract `DecoratorFactory` type into a separate file and reuse it in a consuming decorator factory (in this case `Email`) - the same code for `TestClass` doesn't correctly infer the generics and rather (when hovered) evaluate as `unknown` for `This` and `unknown` for `Value`?

```js
// email.ts
import { DecoratorFactory } from "./shared";

export function Email<This, Value extends string | undefined | null>(
  options?: API.Decorator.Options
): DecoratorFactory<This, Value>;
```

```js
// testclass.ts

import { Email } from "./email";

class TestClass {
  @Email() // <This, Value> evaluates to <unknown, unknown>
  field: string;
}
```

I tried removing the explicit return-type definition, but the result was the same. The TypeScript version in question is v5.2.2